# Prove that if $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R_d})$ and $\phi\in\mathbb{S^d}$ then $f*\phi\in\mathbb{C^\infty}$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, convolution, schwartz-space

Show that if $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R^d})$ and $\phi\in\ S(\mathbb{R^d})$ then $f*\phi\in\mathbb{C^\infty}$, where $S(\mathbb{R^d})$ is the Schwartz class.

How does one prove this rigorously? I have always taken this fact for granted; that convolution of two functions is at least as smooth as either of them. But I cannot get started as to how to prove it in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $1/p + 1/q = 1$ (allowing in particular $p=1,q=\infty$ or $p=\infty,q=1$).
$$(f * \phi)(x) = \int_{\mathbb R^d}
 f(t) \phi(x-t) \; dt $$
(which makes sense since $\phi \in L^q$
Taking derivatives of this, for any multi-index $\alpha$, you should get

$$ \partial^\alpha (f * \phi)(x)
= \int_{\mathbb R^d}
 f(t) \partial^\alpha \phi(x-t) \; dt $$

There is actually a use of the
Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem here, if you do this carefully.

Comment: Thanks. I think I see it now.